# NOT_FOUND - no queue 'async.operations.all' in vhost '/' : RabitMQ : Magento 2.3 EE

Tags: magento2.3, cron, magento2-enterprise, rabbit-mq

I am integrating RabbitMQ with magento 2.3. EE ,

> When I try to run cron It is giving me below error
>
> NOT_FOUND - no queue 'async.operations.all' in vhost '/'

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 26):

Make sure that `app/etc/env.php` queue array is configured like in [Magento's docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html#connect-rabbitmq-to-magento-open-source-or-magento-commerce).

Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` which will create the queues if not already created.

use `bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all` to consume, it will terminate when nothing is left in the queue so set it up from cron or something similar.

Comment: setup:upgrade is key after configuring rabbitmq